# What is the true meaning of bohemian rhapsody?

Tags: meaning, queen

I have noticed that there are many different interpretation of Queen's top hit rock song, Bohemian Rhapsody. Since most of the lyrics are a little unclear and there is a pile of nonsense in the "opera" part, I would want to see if there would be an actual interpretation or explanation of the lyrics by Queen themselves or some people who helped produce the song. I have many curiosities of this great song which helped shape the rock era. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story in the song is about "killing your darlings".

In the writing community, the age-old advice for writers after they complete a work is to find a way to have the characters of your story die so that you can work on your next project.  Sometimes this is done in a fantastical manner where a murder is written in some notes to have the character dead.

Actors also do this when they have developed characters for a very long time and they need to cease the re-creation.  This is especially true for actors who engage in method acting.

There is no official explanation provided by the members of Queen.  To them, they keep it a close secret.  But the clue is in the title.  A "Bohemian" is typically a struggling or eccentric artist.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, there are a ton of different interpretations but the real meaning was kept secret by Freddie Mercury, he wanted people to give their own interpretation of the song, but actually the only person in Earth that knows the meaning as of today (according to Days of Our Lives documentary), is Roger Taylor, but I don't think he will ever give us the real meaning to that song.